# first post :some users can not view community sites in community portal

Tags: community-site

I created community portal  , some users can see the community sites, some users don't.
how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What have you checked so far? E.g. confirming that the users with the problem have a permission for the community sites? What do you mean be "see" - can the users access the sites but content is not available, or are they given some error message?

Comment: when users open the community portal he got the message : there are currently no sites in view.                                                                             i solved it. but now only the members can view the sites , is that true configuration.???? i mean when members open portal they can view only the sites that they member of.

Comment: I forgot to thank you>  one more thing please , I want step by step lab to configure community portal and community site..

Comment: You should create a new question for the requirement of community portal configuring and community site creating, as it is not in the scope of this question and likely won't be answered here.

Comment: And yes, that's intended that user only can see the sites they have access to, and no more than that.